# How to iterate thru all the buttons within a swing interface?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've created a frame with a 3x3 grid of buttons using this code...

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("my 3x3");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    panel.add(upperLeft);
    panel.add(upperCenter);
    panel.add(upperRight);
    panel.add(midLeft);
    panel.add(midCenter);
    panel.add(midRight);
    panel.add(bottomLeft);
    panel.add(bottomCenter);
    panel.add(bottomRight);
    pane.add(panel);
```

... with each of the upper to lower, left to right elements being JButton objects.

Later in the execution, I need a list of these buttons to iterate through to reset them, but all I have at that point is the frame.  I know buried somewhere in the frame object is a list of components, perhaps layers deep, but where?  Is there a straight forward way to retrieve a frame's buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each swing `Container` has `getComponents()`. So, starting from the JFrame (or its `getContentPane()`) you can go down recursively and fetch all components.

But you can also hold a `List<JButton>` and fill it when you add the buttons to the panel.

Answer (score 2):

Since your grid of buttons is 3x3 and since you know this in advance (before the program runs), why not create a 2-dimensional 3x3 array of buttons. Then the button indices will naturally reflect their position.

**Edit: For Example**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ButtonGridGuiPanel extends JPanel {
   // The number of rows and columns
   private static final int MAX_ROWS = 3;
   private static final int MAX_COLS = MAX_ROWS;

   // the size of the button text in "points"
   private static final float BTN_PTS = 64;

   // starting text for button. Has spaces so button isn't too narrow
   private static final String INITIAL_TEXT = "   ";

   // The 2-D JButton array that holds our buttons
   private JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
   private int buttonPressCount = 0;

   public ButtonGridGuiPanel() {
      JPanel buttonGridPanel = new JPanel(); // jpanel to hold the buttons
      buttonGridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS));

      // create an action listener to add to all buttons
      ButtonListener btnListener = new ButtonListener();

      // iterate through the 2-d button array
      for (int row = 0; row < buttonGrid.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < buttonGrid[row].length; col++) {
            // create a new button with blank text
            JButton btn = new JButton(INITIAL_TEXT);
            // set its font
            btn.setFont(btn.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, BTN_PTS));
            // add the action listener
            btn.addActionListener(btnListener);
            buttonGridPanel.add(btn); // add button to the JPanel
            buttonGrid[row][col] = btn; // and add it to the 2-d array
         }
      }

      JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
      resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            reset(); // call the reset method, that's it!
         }
      });
      JPanel resetBtnPanel = new JPanel(); // to hold reset button
      resetBtnPanel.add(resetButton);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // main JPanel uses border layout
      add(buttonGridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // add button grid panel to main
      add(resetBtnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); // add reset btn panel to main
   }

   public void reset() {
      buttonPressCount = 0; // in order that first press gives "X"

      // then iterate through the button grid's rows and columns
      // setting button text back to its initial state
      for (int row = 0; row < buttonGrid.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < buttonGrid[row].length; col++) {
            buttonGrid[row][col].setText(INITIAL_TEXT);
         }
      }
   }

   // a simple action listener that finds out which button has been pressed
   // and sets the button's text alternatingly to "X" or "O"
   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource(); // get pressed button
         String text = btn.getText().trim(); // get its text
         if (text.isEmpty()) { // if text is blank

            // iterate through the 2d button array to find out the 
            // row and col position of the pressed button 
            int rowPressed = -1;
            int colPressed = -1;
            for (int row = 0; row < buttonGrid.length; row++) {
               for (int col = 0; col < buttonGrid[row].length; col++) {
                  if (btn == buttonGrid[row][col]) {
                     // button has been found!
                     rowPressed = row;
                     colPressed = col;
                  }
               }
            }
            // make the button text alternate between X and O 
            text = (buttonPressCount % 2 == 0) ? "X" : "O";
            btn.setText(text); // set the button's text
            buttonPressCount++;

            // TODO: perform whatever logic is necessary based on the row
            // and column position of the button
            System.out.printf("[row, col]: [%d, %d]%n", rowPressed, colPressed);
         }

      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Grid");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new ButtonGridGuiPanel());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // create the GUI in a thread-safe manner
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @dacracot: edit 3: added reset capability and a button that does just that.

Comment: Instead of storing buttons in a mutlidimensional array, you could store it an array with 9 values (if using 3x3) where values would range from 0 to 8.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: true. I'd use whatever structure is easiest to match to the model. Since if I were doing a tic-tac-toe program, my model would likely use a 3 x 3 array of cells, since this would make a check for win algorithm easier since I can use the symmetries of the grid in this test, and so I'd likely leave my view as a 3 x 3 two-dimensional array of JButtons.